# Identifying font and spacing?

Tags: fonts, line-spacing

I am trying to identify the font for the following snippet:

[image]

and also the line spacing between the lines. I tried spotty font identifiers online, but without much help. This might be also a scan, and I am not sure what \usepackage{} for which font to use.

Comment: Looks like Arial (or some Helvetica-kind of font) to me, but do you really only have such a tiny example? Line spacing is about normal, I'd say. But this is probably not the best site to identify fonts anyways.

Comment: If it is in a PDF, it is usually possible to have PDF reader software tell you what fonts are used. Otherwise, I notice that besides the obvious sans-serif, there is no weight difference between thick and thin stems. Other classification involves the relation between Xheight and xheight, the horizontal character widths, and other factors that can get you to a font that is "close enough".

Comment: See the canonical https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture for a number of strategies you can use to identify the font, in case you haven't tried those. For most of those you would need either a pdf or a larger sample or both (if it's a scan), but if you don't have that then there is probably not much of a point trying to identify the font anyway (?).